# how to generate c# class from sql multiple tables (related tables with foreign keys)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, class, generate

I would like to generate C# class from sql queries. I can do it just for a table, but i have a header table and more than one detail tables. I' d like to generate classes for all of them and they are related with pk and fk's.

Comment: Could you elaborate the usage?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ernado-x/7b6f0d9f4acb95e949d5 i am using this for a table but, i want to use for related tables. i have tables related with foreign keys and i cant do this for them

Comment: Have you considered using ORM tools like Dapper or Entity Framework or are you trying to avoid the extra overhead? No right or wrong answer here, just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment, hence the answer.

This answer isn't perfect because it's for oracle. I use bellow code to run a query and get access to the results. You can easily generate classes from this.

```
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection oracleConnection = new OracleConnection(constr))
        {
            oracleConnection.Open();
            OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand(query, oracleConnection);
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(oracleCommand);

            //TODO: This seems to get all the data. We just want 1 row or no rows and only column info..
            da.Fill(dataTable);

            oracleConnection.Close();//Close just in case
        }

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        {
            //Use these properties to generate a class
            column.ColumnName;
            column.DataType;
            column.AllowDBNull; 
            column.DefaultValue;
        }
```

Comment: I appreciate your giving me time, thank you very much.